# How to make listview all over the top-down screen

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two ListViews in a single page, and i want them to display in such a way that just once that i scroll the first one down to the button the second one follows. How can i do this?

So far i am able to display both ListViews, but they split the screen into two, being the first list view on top, and the second one at the button (see screenshot below!)

[image]

What i want to achieve is like in the image in the following link:

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/2568324/screenshots/6893977/dribbble8.png

My code is as follows:

```
    <Frame>
        <ListView x:Name = "MainMagazine" RowHeight="200" ItemSelected="MainMagazine_se" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>

                            <Image Source = "{Binding Urlimage}" WidthRequest = "400" Margin="0,-200" HeightRequest = "500" MinimumHeightRequest = "500" MinimumWidthRequest = "400" />

                            <StackLayout Margin="0,45" >
                                <Label Text = "{Binding Title}" FontSize = "15" TextColor = "Black"/>
                                <Label Text = "{Binding MiniContent}" FontSize = "12" TextColor = "Gray" Margin="0,-7"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Frame>

    <Frame>
        <ListView x:Name = "MainMagazine2" RowHeight="200" ItemSelected="MainMagazine_se" VerticalOptions="Center" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,300">

                            <Image Source = "{Binding Urlimage}" WidthRequest = "400" Margin="0,-200" HeightRequest = "500" MinimumHeightRequest = "500" MinimumWidthRequest = "400" />

                            <StackLayout Margin="0,45" >
                                <Label Text = "{Binding Title}" FontSize = "15" TextColor = "Black"/>
                                <Label Text = "{Binding MiniContent}" FontSize = "12" TextColor = "Gray" Margin="0,-7"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Frame>
```

Comment: Use a grid with 2 rows, each 50%.  Then place a ListView in each row

Comment: Jason, You can to show me how to do this?

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: if you see new the image in the top, you can to see two list cuts in the center. i dont want that, i want two lists but not cut in the screen, like that [link](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/2568324/screenshots/6893977/dribbble8.png)

Comment: So you want to be able to scroll the first down to the end, and just then the second list view should appear?

Comment: yes, that what i want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to set two **ListView**s, one above the other, so that you can scroll one down to the button, and just then see the second one and continue to scroll that one, you could put both of your **ListView**s inside a `ScrollView`:

Your view should be something like:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
            <Frame>
                ...
            </Frame>

            <Frame>
                ...
            </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You should never be nesting ListViews inside a ScrollView. Very bad practice! The ListView implements its own scrolling. The ListView will not receive any gestures, as they will be handled by the parent ScrollView. The ListView can present a customized header and footer that scrolls with the elements of the list, potentially offering the functionality that the ScrollView was used for.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @TaiT's, but no one asked for best practices. OP had a question, my answer solved the problem... That's how this works... If you have a better (best practice-like) way to solve THE PROBLEM AS STATED IN OP, feel free to post it. I would also be interested in learning from it.